# Use multiple Nest.js app as Express middleware

Tags: javascript, express, graphql, nestjs

I've multiple Nestjs app (Graphql) that I would like to import in another node module, as a simple Express middleware (not a Nest middleware). Actually it works but I got the message:

```
Skip parsing message which is plain text: Cannot GET /admin/graphql
Skip parsing message which is plain text: Cannot POST /admin/graphql
Skip parsing message which is plain text: Cannot GET /client/graphql
Skip parsing message which is plain text: Cannot POST /client/graphql
```

## admin.module.ts

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { GraphQLError } from 'graphql'
import { RequestContextMiddleware } from '..'

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      path: '/admin/graphql',
      playground: true,
      cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true
      },
      formatError: (error: GraphQLError) => {
        console.log('error', error)

        const graphQLFormattedError = {
          statusCode: error.extensions?.exception?.status || 500,
          message: error.extensions?.exception?.response?.message || error.message,
          messageCode: error.extensions?.exception?.messageCode || error.message
        }
        return graphQLFormattedError
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: []
})
export class AdminModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(RequestContextMiddleware).forRoutes('*')
  }
}
```

## adminServer.ts

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware, ValidationPipe, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common'
import { NestFactory, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core'
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express'
import { Express, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'
import { AdminModule } from './admin.module'

let cachedServer: INestApplication

const bootstrap = async (express: Express.Application) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AdminModule, new ExpressAdapter(express))
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }))
    cachedServer = await app.init()
  }

  return cachedServer
}

@Injectable()
export class AdminMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  constructor(private expressInstance: Express.Application) {}

  async use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await bootstrap(this.expressInstance)
    next()
  }
}
```

## client.module.ts

```
same admin.module.ts with other path
```

## clientServer.ts

```
same adminServer.ts
```

## main.ts

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common'
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import express from 'express'

import { config } from '../config'
import { AdminMiddleware } from './adminServer'
import { ClientMiddleware } from './clientServer'

async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const { port } = config
    const app = express()

    // NOTE: body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())

    app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
      await new AdminMiddleware(app).use(req, res, next)
      await new ClientMiddleware(app).use(req, res, next)
      next()
    })

    const server = await app.listen(port)

    if (module.hot) {
      module.hot.accept()
      module.hot.dispose(() => server.close())
    }
  } catch (error) {
    process.exit()
  }
}

bootstrap()
```

How can I no longer show the above error message every time I call the API?